# Calculations within groupby in pandas, python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, math, calculation

My data set contains house price for 4 different house types (A,B,C,D) in 4 different countries (USA, Germany, Uk, sweden). House price can be only three types (Upward, Downward, and Not Changed). I want to calculate Difition index (ID) for different House types (A,B,C,D) for different countries (USA, Germany, Uk, sweden) based on house price.

The formula that I want to use to calculate Difition index (DI) is:

> DI = (Total Number of Upward * 1 + Total Number of Downward * 0 + Total Number of Not Changed * 0.5) / (Total Number of Upward + Total Number of Downward + Total Number of Not Changed)

Here is my data:

[image]

and the expected result is:

[image]

I really need your help.
Thanks.

Comment: Please provide your data and results in data format, not an image, and also provide any code you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using `groupby` and assuming your file is named as `text.xlsx`

```
df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')
df = df.replace({'Upward':1,'Downward':0,'Notchanged':0.5})
df.groupby('Country').mean().reset_index()
```